# Write a Word 2007 document in OpenXML

Tags: openxml

My problem is in two parts:

1. How can I, in Word 2007, put an id on a section so I can easy access this section from my code? For example, if I have `Name` : Here I want to set the name from my C# code.
2. How can I, from my C# code, fill this section id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use Content Controls in Word (and the Content Control Toolkit). There are tons of examples out there, like:

- http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2006/11/open-xmlword-2007-content-control.html
- http://www.vsj.co.uk/articles/display.asp?id=657
- http://www.craigmurphy.com/blog/?p=913